# How can i delete row tables in mysql with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to delete specific rows in mysql by jquery. It works on the first row, but in the second row, nothing happens.

This is my HTML code:

```
     <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">
       <button id="dele_com" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" name="<?php echo $rows['companyID']; ?>">
        <span class="icon-trash"></span>
       </button></p>
     </td>
```

and this is my jquery code:

```
$("#dele_com").on("click", function(event) {        
 var show_id = this.name;
            alert(show_id);
            bootbox.dialog({
              message: "Are you sure you want to Delete this account ?",
              title: "<i class='icon-trash'></i> Delete !",
              buttons: {
                success: {
                  label: "No",
                  className: "btn-success",
                  callback: function() {
                     $('.bootbox').modal('hide');
                  }
                },
                danger: {
                  label: "Delete!",
                  className: "btn-danger",
                  callback: function() {
                      $.post('update_delete.php', { 'pid1':pid1 })
                      .done(function(response){
                          window.location.href= "modification.php";
                      })
                      .fail(function(){
                          bootbox.alert('Something Went Wrog ....');
                      })
                  }
                }
              }
            });
});
```

Comment: `jquery` is client side, `mysql` is server side. You have to use `ajax` from the client, that calls a php script on the server that does the database query.

Comment: You should probably show your `php` code then, more specifically your `mysql` query.

Comment: where should `pid1` come from?? I guess you want it to be `show_id`, right?

Comment: @Nytrix Yep, right, my comment points to the question topic! There is no way to `delete` something with jquery in a `mysql` database. Sometimes i get a little nerdy :) One of my bad comments i thing

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I thought that, I can get a little picky. We keep eachother in balance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have specified the id **#dele_com** and that will be the same for every row. So when you click on the delete button it will find the first id of your table and performs click.

You have to use class selector instead of id then it will work